# HeadingFormat in word Table Style

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I would like to set the option "Repeat as header row at the top of each page" in word with C# in a table style like "Table Grid".

I know how to do it if there is a table in the word already:

table[1].Rows.HeadingFormat = true

The question is how to do it within the table style with C#?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft, for some reason, forgot to implement this property for Table Styles in the Word object model, back when Word 2007 introduced table styles.

And never got around to fixing it, that I'm aware.

The only way I know of would be to use Word Open XML to add the property to the style definition. Unfortunately, changing style definitions by inserting Word Word Open XML into the opened document, using the interop, doesn't work (I learned that the hard way!). But if you create a new style - that has a chance of working.